# Redirect the editing of nested content

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Problem resolve
When I want to edit an existing section an error appears:

> "Couldn't find Category with'id' ="

And my page is redirected to "http://localhost:3000/sections/1" when it should be redirected to "http://localhost:3000/**categories/3**/sections/1/".

**sections_controller.rb**

```rb
class SectionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_the_category

  def index
    @sections = @category.sections
  end


  def show
    @section = @category.sections.find(params[:id])
  end


  def new
    @section = Section.new
  end


  def edit
    @section = @category.sections.find(params[:id])
  end


  def create
    @section = @category.section.create(section_params)
    flash[:success] = "Section ajouté avec succés"

    if @section.save    
      redirect_to category_section_path(@category, @section)
    end    
  end


  def update
    flash[:success] = "Section modifié avec succés"
    @section = @category.sections.find(params[:id])
    @section.update(section_params)
    redirect_to category_section_path(@category, @section)
  end


  def destroy
    flash[:danger] = "Section supprimé"
    @section = Section.find(params[:id])
    @section.destroy
    redirect_to category_sections_path

  end

  private
    def find_the_category
      @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    end

    def section_params
      params.require(:section).permit(:title, :content)
    end


end
```

**routes.rb**

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :categories do
    resources :sections
  end
end
```

**section#_form.html.erb**

```rb
<%= bootstrap_form_for([@category, @section]) do |f| %>
  <% if @section.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@section.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this reponse from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @section.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Titre %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**category.rb**

```rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    # une catégorie peut avoir plusieurs questions relations has-many
    has_many :questions
    has_many :sections
end
```

**section.rb**

```rb
class Section < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :category
end
```

Comment: can you provide your Category et Section model code please?

Comment: Show your edit form pls

Comment: I updated my content @johan

Comment: I updated my content @nuT707

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your form url in browser, i think it wrong.

You don't provide any category to bootstrap_form_for helper, so it may generate wrong link.

Your form template must be smth like this:

```
bootstrap_form_for([@category, @section])
```

Comment: thanks , i'm stupid, i've ctrl c and ctrl v the form of reponse who depends to question but i've just modified "reponse"

Comment: that's normal) it is the reason while coding in pairs is awesome